# How to get cursor to read next line from SQLite Database?

Tags: android, sqlite, pdf

I am trying to get a report from my database from certain fields to an PDF.  The pdf is generating perfectly but it is only reading the first entry from the database instead of all the entries.

This is my code for the PDF:

```
public void exportDataBaseIntoPDF() {
    Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4);
    try {
        path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/MSS Jobsheets";
        date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());

        File dir = new File(path);
        if (!dir.exists())
            dir.mkdirs();

        Log.d("PDFCreator", "PDF Path: " + path);

        filePDF = new File(dir, "Report" + "(" + date + ")" + ".pdf");
        FileOutputStream fOut = null;
        try {
            fOut = new FileOutputStream(filePDF);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, fOut);
        doc.open();

        DBHelper db = new DBHelper(this);
        Cursor cursor = db.getDataItem();
        int count = cursor.getCount();

        cursor.moveToFirst();

        for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
            PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
            table.addCell(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name")));
            table.addCell(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("gender")));


            cursor.moveToNext();

            doc.add(table);
            doc.close();
        }

    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is pulling the data from my DBHelper class:

```
 public Cursor getDataItem() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String q = "SELECT * FROM " + PERSON_TABLE_NAME;
    Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery(q, null);

    return mCursor;
}
}
```

But like I said, it only reads the first line from the database and adds the data but does not move on to the next line in the database to add the data in the PDF.

Could some one please assist me with this issue?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have multiple rows in the database?

Comment: Yes, i do have.  Basically its a form users fill in, then at the end of the day the user can pull a report from certain fields then email.

Comment: try to close doc out side for loop. write this line doc.close(); out side for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actual Problem is not related to a cursor, cursor read the next line but you close the document after first data write. try to close the document object outside of for loop.

put this line to the outside of `for loop`

```
 doc.close();
```

Comment: Thanks! its working now.  I can't believe how I missed that!  I been struggling for ages with this!

Comment: @Newbie happy to help you..!